# Composer name spacing "use as" not working in my case

Tags: composer-php, autoload, psr-4

Like everybody else, I have a composer.json file in my root directory. In this case, specifying the psr-4 method:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CMS\\Templating\\": "Framework/Templating"
        }
    }
```

When I am trying to edit any other files with a call to the Template file, like so:

```
use CMS\Templating as Template;
```

I can't access the template class via:

```
Template::functionName();
```

But it works if I do this(without specifying use):

```
\CMS\Templating\Template::functionName();
```

How can that be? Regarding structure, it should be fine, unless I am missing something?

```
-Root
--Framework
---Templating
----Template.php (namespace CMS\Templating) 
--Controllers  
---frontend
----contact.php (use CMS\Templating as Template)
```

Comment: Off course the reason why it did work with \CMS\Templating\Template::functionName(); was that here I specified the template class, which I did not do the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `use` statement is not correct. Please try

```
use CMS\Templating\Template;

Template::functionName();
```

Comment: Off course. I missed the name: Template. Thanks for your help, it worked :-)